# Force React to treat an update as low priority

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-16

I see that react 18 has some cool hooks to help manually control the priority of state updates (useDeferredValue and useTransition) and using these methods fixes some performance issues that I have on a table. But React 18 isn't stable yet!

So I am wondering if there is a way to handle this is React 16 / 17? Is there a way to tell the reconciler to tag my row updates as low priority so that a user's typing updates will always interrupt and take precedence over the table rendering the rows?

*For a tiny bit more context, my issue is that I have a search box and a table on a page. The initial data displayed in the table rows is unfiltered, but when the user types in the search box, I make a query to the backend and get a filtered list of data. When that data comes back, I render it into the table.
I can (and do) use a debounce on the query so that only if the user stops typing for 500ms do I fetch data. But this only helps when the user is typing faster than 500ms per letter AND it adds 500ms to the user experience of retrieving the data on every single call. I'd like something that feels more responsive.*

**The React 18 updates solve my problem perfectly. Looking for a way to do this in React 17.**

Comment: You could possibly wrap the row components being rendered in the `React.memo` HOC and provide a custom `areEqual` props compare function, introducing a new prop specific to when you *actually* want the row to update. As-is, it seems like you've already done what you can to help the performance.

Comment: The problem is that the new rows ARE different, so the areEqual comparison would be false

Comment: You can return true/false when you want it to, that's the point. I'm not sure though what your performance issue is though, so maybe you're trying to prevent state updates from occurring instead of my suggestion which would only help with rerendering performance. You could try adding cancel tokens to the network requests so if the underlying "state" making the requests is stale then you can cancel the requests that will have their responses thrown away anyway.

Comment: I want them to re-render everytime I get new data back unless the user types in the search box again, in which case I want the typing to interrupt what react is doing and I want react to handle the keystroke (like useDeferredValue). Currently, once the table begins its rendering, it doesn't stop until all the rows are iterated over and THEN the keystroke can be handled. So the UX is a lag in the typing.

Comment: Then no, React v16/17 don't do that. Best you can likely do is either prevent state updates that trigger unnecessary rerenders, use `memo` HOC to hint at unnecessary rerenders, or virtualize the table UI so you aren't rerendering the entire table each render cycle.

Comment: React 16 already prioritizes updates. I just looking for a way to have more control over that... Thanks for your input